# applyTransaction remove not working with id

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using ag-grid in Angular9 project. I'm using Transactions to do CRUD operations in grid when my backend request resolve. I need to provide RowNodeId myself, i dont want to use object-references as i have large data set.

Thing is, i've provided the ID and i can add/update item in the grid but i'm unable to delete the item. In Doc it [mentions](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update-transactions/#providing-row-node-ids), you only need to provide id to remove the item but i'm getting the following error.

[image]

Here's the code.

```
class HostAppListPage
{

@ViewChild('agGrid', {static: true}) grid:AgGridAngular;


constructor()
{
}


ngOnInit()
{
    this.grid.getRowNodeId = (data) => {
        return data.entityId;
    };


    this.columns = [
        {headerName: 'App Name', field: 'name', rowDrag: true, headerCheckboxSelection: true, checkboxSelection: true},
        {headerName: 'App Id', field: 'id'},
        {headerName: 'Compatibility', field: COMPATIBILITY'},
        {headerName: 'Creation', field: 'createdAtToString'},
        {headerName: 'Last Update', field: 'updatedAtToString'}
    ];
}


deleteRow()
{
    let ids = this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes()
           // .map((row) => {
               // return {id: row.entityId}
               // return row.entityId;
           // });


    console.log(ids);
    this.grid.api.applyTransaction({remove: ids});
}
```

I tried both with and without map statement, nothing worked
but my Add and Update works fine.

Comment: Ok, i figured my mistake. I need to make following changes inside map
return {entityId: row.data.entityId};

Answer (score 1):

Replace map with following code.

```
.map((row) => {
   return {entityId: row.data.entityId};
});
```

it should be the the same field **(entityId)** which i set in **getRowNodeId** function.

Answer (score 1):

In a typical situation, where one does not define a `getRowNodeId`, one should be able to do:

```
const removeData: any[] = [{id: rowNode0.id}, {id: rowNode1.id}, ...];
applyTransaction({remove: removeData});
```

where rowNode0, rowNode1, etc. are the nodes you want to remove.

However when you provide your own `getRowNodeId` callback, ag-grid will fetch the id's by applying your callback on the data you provided. Therefore, the name(s) in the data must match those used in your callback. That's why `return {id: row.entityId}` doesn't work, but `return {entityId: row.entityId}` does.

In other words, if one defines:

```
this.grid.getRowNodeId = (data) => {
    return data.column1 + data.column5 + data.column2;
};
```

Then one would need to provide

```
const removeData: any[] = [
    {column1: 'a1', column2: 'b1', column5: 'c1'},
    {column1: 'a2', column2: 'b2', column5: 'c2'},
    {column1: 'a3', column2: 'b3', column5: 'c3'},
];
```

so that ag-grid would have all the names it needs to find the id's via the given `getRowNodeId`.